# Entity Framework complaining about required fields when saveChanges even if valid data are setted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, postgresql, devart

I'm using Entity Framework (DbContext with database first) with MVC. When user save from a form, I have a condition in the controller that send the entity to the **update** of **insert** method depending of some internal flag of mine.

When sending entity to the update method, I flag it to modified using `context.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;`,  I call saveChanges() and everything work well.

When sending the entity to the insert method, I flag it to added using `context.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Added;` but when calling saveChanges() I receive error about 2 fields that are required...

The problem is that thoses 2 fields are not empty and they effectively contain valid data just before saving... I have even try to force new values to thoses 2 fields just before saving but same error.

It may be usefull to mention that I'm using Devart DotConnect For PostgreSQL as db provider.

Any idea how to debug this problem?

**EDIT:**

Here is the error:

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

When looking for this EntityValidationErrors I receive the 2 following specific errors:

> The flg_actif field is required
>
> The user_creation field is required

As mentionned before, those fields are filled with data just before saving so I don't understand what is happening.

I'm using EF v4.0.30319 (system.data.entity=> v4.0 and EntityFramework=> v4.4)

**EDIT2:**
Just to clarify a little bit more: The entity I'm trying to insert already exist in database. The form show the data of this database row. When saving, I decide if I update the row (this work well) but sometime, I need to insert the edited row as a new register instead of updating it to keep an history of the change in database.

Comment: Start by having a look what is sent across the wire to the database server. Be useful to include the text and stack trace of the error also.

Comment: You can get a query log from the PostgreSQL end by setting `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` ; alternately, enable SQL logging in Entity Framework. The versions of the tools you're using would also be helpful. BTW, please always include the *full, exact text of any error messages*.

Comment: I have setted the log for PostgreSQL but no query is sent to database as the saveChanges() fail.

Comment: This is an error generated by EF as it notes the fields as required, but not set. As such it stops there, and won't actually send out the SQL. I suggest you check via break points / Intellitrace exactly what these variables are set to within the context before you save the changes.

Comment: I put a break point on the context.saveChanges() statement. drilling down this context => myEntity => Results View => ... I can see all the fields of my entity and thoses two fields contains the values: true and "etides" as the first one is a bool and the second one is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you verify if the EntityKey property is set or null on the items you are trying to save?

If it already has a key, the context is already aware of the item, and you should use Attach instead of setting the state to added manually.

EDIT: To summarise the point from below. It looks like what you are doing is inserting a new copy of a row already associated with a context. That is almost certainly your problem. Try creating a fresh object *based* on your original row (i.e. copy the variable values or use a copy constructor), then add that new object.

Additionally, you should not need to set the state manually on a newly added object. You are trying to force the state here because the context doesn't see that item as a new one.

Comment: There is no EntityKey property on my entity and when trying to Attach the entity I receive the error: System.InvalidOperationException: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Comment: Ok, the lack of key confirms it's a new item to the context. Just out of interest, where are you actually adding the item to the set?

Comment: I fact I don't say that the EntityKey is null but instead that I don't see anywhere this EntityKey property... I'm using DbContext and not ObjectContext... I think this may be the reason...

Comment: This entity is created as a parameter of my controller when user save form. I'm adding the item to the set like this:             context.MyEntities.Add(myEntity); after that I call saveChanges() that fail. Instead of using .Add I have tried context.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Added; but same result.

Comment: Ok, at that point the state should be handled automatically, is there a reason you set the state manually?

Comment: I'm just following the basic MVC/EF tutorial... The only difference is that I'm trying to insert a row from an entity already existing that has been modified in the form... I just don't want to lose the original row by making a copy of it...

Comment: I set the state manually just to try because using .Add was not working. Anyway, both ways fails with same error...

Comment: Ah hah... ok, so the most likely cause of your problem is that the context is seeing that entity as associated with a different context, or instance of the context. Your best bet: Make a copy of the object (use a copy constructor) you want to insert that so it's 'fresh' and add that.

Comment: Not really sure how to do correctly that copy... I try to detach the entity first (context.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Detached;) and Add it after but same error when saving...

Comment: If you are adding a new row, you shouldn't be detaching and re-attaching because it's a recipe for problems. What you want is a new row, based of an existing one. Row r = new row(), r.prop1 = oldRow.prop1 etc, context.add(r)

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick. it work when creating explicitly a new entity.